# How to pass a string value from a class to another on the same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a viewcontroller which consists of two classes. These are displayed below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Viewholder: UIImageView!
    var txt:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vv= TestView(frame: Viewholder.frame) 
        view.addSubview(vv)

        txt= "hello"
        let rr = TestView(frame: self.view.frame,textvalue:txt!)

        rr.colour = "" // set value

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

class TestView: UIView {

    var textvalue:String?

    init(frame: CGRect,textvalue) {
        self.textvalue= textvalue
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.sharedLayout()       
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
        self.setupPaths()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func sharedLayout() {
        print(textvalue!) // works here 
    }

    func setupPaths() {
        print(textvalue!)  // doesnt work here (displays nil)   
    }
```

How can I make it work so that the value of textvalue in "setupPaths" gives the correct value so that I can then changee the text of a label. I am having trouble getting the setuppath function to display the passed value as it is returning null. This is stopping me from editting the label with a passed value.

Comment: Note that this controller doesn't 'consist' of two classes. They just happen to be in the same file. Now, assuming that the variable is an instance one, you would instantiate a `TestView` and pass the value of `colour` to one of its properties. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: @Alladinian I am quite new to swift programming , could u possibly give an example of how a variable can be passed onto the UIView.

Comment: Sure, but I would suggest reading Apple's guides and/or any tutorials to familiarize yourself with the language and the frameworks. A basic example would be `let myView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))` and then assuming that you have a colour (String) property  on your view -> `myView.colour = self.colour`. PS: It's a strange decision to have a `colour` property defined as `String` don't you think?

Comment: @Alladinian sry I was just creating an example of my problem therefore I used that string name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customView like this

```
class TestView: UIView {

    var colour:String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.sharedLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.sharedLayout()
    }

    init(frame: CGRect,colour:String) {
      self.colour = colour
      super.init(frame: frame)
      self.sharedLayout()
    }
    func sharedLayout() {

    }

}
```

//

You can create it like this

```
let rr = TestView(frame: self.view.frame,colour:"test")

// rr.colour = "" // set value
```

Comment: but how can i pass the value from the viewcontroller to this variable inside UIView

Comment: I have tested this code however it returns nil if i put for example "test"

Comment: you can call setupPaths inside sharedLayout

Comment: try it in awakeFromNib function , Also don;t forget to add the label to the view

Answer (score 0):

You are badly confused about object-oriented programming. In your code:

```
    let vv= TestView(frame: Viewholder.frame) 
    view.addSubview(vv)

    txt= "hello"
    let rr = TestView(frame: self.view.frame,textvalue:txt!)
```

The `let vv` line creates a TestView object and installs it as a subview of the view controller's content view.

Then the next 2 lines create a NEW instance of TestView and install text into that 2nd view. You then forget about this second view.

This is like buying a new car, setting the station on the radio of the new car, abandoning the new car, and then going home and wondering why the radio station on your existing car didn't change. The two objects are not the same object and settings in one instance of `TestView` have no effect on the other instance of `TestView`.

Comment: Yes I realised that I forgot to delete the first instance but managed to get it working. Thank you